# How do I convert to camera pose in world from rvec and tvec of cv2.SolvePnP

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, opencv, quaternions, opencv-solvepnp

I'm trying to get quaternions and translations out of rvec and tvec with code like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation
# 2d
image_points_2D = [[1331.284,610],[1473.253,468.6115], [1191.823,748.8911],[1473.253,751.3885],[1191.823,471.1088],[1245.413,347.5563],[1501.027,477.5027],[1487.591,610]]
# 3d
figure_points_3D =[[ 0. ,0., -0.5 ], [ 0.5, 0.5, -0.5 ],[-0.5,-0.5,-0.5 ],[ 0.5 , -0.5, -0.5 ],[-0.5 ,  0.5, -0.5 ],[-0.45,  1. ,  0.4 ],[ 0.5 ,  0.5,  0.5 ],[ 0.5 ,  0. ,  0.  ]]
# camera
distortion_coeffs = np.zeros((4,1))
matrix_camera = np.array([[flx, 0, center_x],
                          [0, fly, center_y],
                          [0, 0, 1         ]], dtype = "double")
# PnP
success, vector_rotation, vector_translation = cv2.solvePnP(figure_points_3D, image_points_2D, matrix_camera, distortion_coeffs, flags=cv2.SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE)
# get loss
reprojected_points, _ = cv2.projectPoints(figure_points_3D, vector_rotation, vector_translation, matrix_camera, distortion_coeffs)
loss = np.mean(np.abs(image_points_2D - reprojected_points.reshape(image_points_2D.shape)))
print("loss", loss)

# get pose
rotation = Rotation.from_rotvec(vector_rotation.flatten())
print("quat (x,y,z,w): ", rotation.as_quat())
print("translation", vector_translation.flatten())
```

Here the Loss value is displayed as 0, so I think the rvec and tvec values are correct.

On Unity (Game Engine), the camera look the target at the origin position (0,0,0) on Unity from camera position (-2, 0, -15) and pose (XYZW: 0, -0.131, 0, 0.991). The value of tvec is correct. However, the quaternion that converted from the rvec values have their y and w components inverted. Why is this?

Expected quaternion (Unity): (XYZW: 0, -0.131, 0, 0.991)

Output quaternion (solvePnP): (XYZW: 0, -0.991, 0, 0.131)

Comment: quats have one degree of freedom beyond what's needed to express 3D rotations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Even if the rvec and tvec values are wrong, running cv2.projectPoints transforms the 3d points to the same positions as the landmarks on the image. Why is this? When converted to quaternion or Euler, a strange value is displayed as if one axis is reversed.

Comment: I solved this problem. I got the correct quaternion by converting the local coordinate system to the world coordinate system after converting the OpenCV coordinate system to the Unity coordinate system.